# Is there a way to automatically convert any field of type int to a hashed string?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, hash, prisma

I am looking for a way that is not too hacky to hash all ids before returning to user, is there a way to do so? I've searched all over docs and couldn't find anything that handles all scenarios.

I am using Postgres + Prisma ORM and have multiple models with relational fields. Ideally I would achieve the desired behavior using Prisma.

I have tried Jordan reply and my code looks like this.

```
const getPrismaClient = () => {
  const client = new PrismaClient();
  client.$extends({
    result: {
      blog: {
        // We basically create a virtual `hashedId` field
        hashedId: {
          needs: { id: true },
          compute(client) {
            return intToHashedString(client.id);
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
  client.blog
    .findMany({
      select: { hashedId: true },
    })
    .then((r) => {
      console.log(r);
    });
  return client;
};
```

but it throws this error

```
error - unhandledRejection: PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.blog.findMany()` invocation:
{
  select: {
    hashedId: true,
    ~~~~~~~~
?   id?: true,
?   title?: true,
?   slug?: true,
?   image?: true,
?   description?: true,
?   views?: true,
?   authorId?: true,
  clientVersion: '4.11.0'
}
```

Comment: You tagged postgresql and prisma. You should be more specific on exactly where you want to be hashing your IDs. Do you want to achieve it through the Prisma ORM? Do you want it implemented via the Postgresql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Prisma Client results extension](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/client-extensions/result) (They're still under a feature flag, so at your own risk).

First enable the feature

```
// schema.prisma
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["clientExtensions"]
}
```

And then, here is how you could use it:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { scrypt } from 'node:crypto';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const xprisma = prisma.$extends({
  result: {
    client: {
      // We basically create a virtual `hashedId` field
      hashedId: {
        needs: { id: true },
        compute(client: { id: string }) {
          return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
            // I used scrypt here as an example
            scrypt(client.id, 'salt', 64, (err, hashed) => {
              if (err) return reject(err);
              return resolve(hashed.toString('hex'));
            })
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

//                    ,--- Using xprisma, instead of prisma
//                   v
const client = await xprisma.client.findFirst({
  where: { id: '092a5486-9ca2-4c4c-85e6-da7cedb281a5' },
  // hashedId is then autocompleted in available fields
  select: { hashedId: true },
});
```

You'll need to handle performance issues, but it should answer your need.

EDIT: Note that `prisma.$extends` returns a new `PrismaClient` which will include your extensions. Otherwise, it won't compile. Here's why I kept the doc's convention of using `xprisma`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it throws an error, I've modified my answer to include details of my code and the error thrown

Comment: `$extends` returns a new instance of the prisma client with your added extensions, it doesn't mutate the existing one. You need to use `xprisma`, instead of `prisma`.

Answer (score 1):

There are undocumented, but [largely safe-to-use](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAGHENJ5MnkKeymEVFO6daga6qzTruG91u9yeuwkBuTZ_xRSPRg%40mail.gmail.com) hashing functions for every built-in data type in Postgres. Those are used for hash partitioning and indexing, among other things. For `integer` (`int4`) input:

```
hashint4(int) → int
hashint4extended(int, bigint) → bigint
```

The second form requires Postgres 12 or later, additionally takes a seed as 2nd parameter, and produces a larger `bigint` hash to make collisions less likely.

**Or**, to avoid hash collisions almost certainly, go even bigger with the good old [`md5()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) function to get strings of 32 characters (matching a UUID). Related:

- [What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115316/3684)

But `md5()` takes `text`, so you have to cast your `integer` input.
Examples:

```sql
SELECT hashint4(my_id)            AS my_id_int4_hash
     , hashint4extended(my_id, 0) AS my_id_int8_hash
     , hashint4(my_id)            AS my_id_md5_hash
FROM   tbl
LIMIT  10;
```

Cast numeric results to `text` with `::text` if you insist on "strings".

Related (consider the chapter *"Probability of a hash collision?"*):

- [Why doesn't my UNIQUE constraint trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/299107/3684)

You might create a [(`MATERIALIZED`) `VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-creatematerializedview.html) of your table with hashed values to save some typing and computation (though the functions are very performant).

Comment: While this is the correct answer in the context of Postgresql, considering the OP tagged Prisma I think he/she would want to achieve this programmatically through the ORM. Doing this directly through Postgresql would cause schema drift between the Prisma schema and DB schema. Just something to note. The OP should have been more specific in the question.

Comment: Thank you Erwin for your answer but John is correct, I think I should've been more clear about the way I want to achieve, my bad, ideally I want to achieve it using prisma orm, I've tried prisma.$use but it's a bit hacky and requires a lot of edge cases depending on every request.